# Android: How to make an emulator in size of a real device?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to lunch my Android application on an emulator. **The point is i want to make the emulator in the size of the real device**. Although I used `-scale 0.8`, it's still much bigger than real size

Comment: if you will real scale your emulator, you will not able to see small icons with 3" and 4" size. It doesn't matter size on screen. But the specification and attributes what you have provided to your emulator is important

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions that you set in the emulator are in inches, which match into the corresponding real device resolution and if you select to, dimensions on your resulting monitor image.

But consider that your monitor may translate that..

If you really wish to have the same dimensions in the resulting image on screen compared to the device in your hands, why not adapt the dimensions yourself until you're happy with the result? In eclipse: Window -> Android Virtual Device Manager -> Device Definitions -> New Device

Create the device with the dimensions it should have (you may look in [gsmarena](http://www.gsmarena.com/))  then run the emulator on real size making sure your monitor/video card is not scaling (extended desktop with multiple monitors). If not just tune the dimensions when creating the virtual device until you get what you want

Comment: There is the option: "Scale display to real size"

Comment: @UrielFrankel that's what I had in mind when I wrote 'run the emulator on real size'. If it's not some scaling after the video card or some multi screen setup, what else can it be?